# How do I hide a Spring Boot "GET" API request from the public in a browser?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, model-view-controller, hide

As the question states, my goal is to hide a GET route in **Spring Boot** from being accessed from the public. I originally took a CORS approach, but that doesn't solve the actual **view** problem. Pretty much anyone could go to, say... `https://my-api-url.com/employee/all` and see a JSON record of all employees in my database.

**END GOAL:** I only want my front-end to have access to my API for displaying that information to an authorized user who is signed in, but I do NOT want just anyone to have access to the API. CORS policy can handle the ajax requests, but it doesn't seem like I can stop the overall viewing of the GET url.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Hi Matthew, maybe I misunderstood what you're looking for. My suggestion would be you better look at spring security which has been designed such cases.

Comment: Hi there! My goal is to allow CORS to access data from my API, but I don't want the API data to be viewed in the browser directly from that API call. Spring security works great for a lot of things, but I haven't found anything that can block direct viewing of a request in the browser. i.e. ... I don't want to go to `localhost:9000/employee/all` and see the response at the API route.

Answer (score 1):

You can use OAuth to register clients(frontend/postman/whatever you are using to test the API) that can access your resource server, but it might be overkill. For now, if you worry someone can view your API by typing it in the address bar(if that is your question) then you can allow access for authenticated users only.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to restrict usage and make it inconvenient for abusers to call your API, you can issue a token on page load (CSRF token) and require that token to be present in the request to the API - that way the API will be callable from a browser that initiated a page load.

You can refer this link https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/246434/how-can-i-ensure-my-api-is-only-called-by-my-client

Answer (score 0):

If your frontend is currently handling authentication, i‘d suggest moving to Springs Authenticationserice. That way you could prevent unauthenticated users from accessing that specific API endpoint.

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't quite solve the problem. My frontend isn't built yet, but I can handle the cors side great. What I don't want is a user to go to my API URL and see a JSON response in their browser. This way the only place that can retrieve data is my frontend & users are denied viewing access to the URL.

Comment: In that case, I'm having a hard time understanding what you're trying to do. I assumed you were going to use Spring as a Backend and create an API, where people can access endpoints and get/post JSON data. Did I understand that correctly? I don't see how you'd be able to see anything in a browser anyway. Or are you using an API auto documentation tool that lets you test youre endpoints over the web?
If you ARE using an auto API docu feature, you can just ignore the api endpoint with a simple annotation.

Comment: Or, again, use Authentication to require a Token when accessing an endpoint and it will also send back "unauthorized" on the API docu tool.

Comment: BTW: If you're using the API docu to test your app, I'd suggest swithcing to an external program (like Postman for example) to test your API. You're much more flexible that way.